# Have an issue accessing hidden field array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am having an issue accessing a hidden field value in Node JS. I am trying to pass an array as hidden field value on submit of a form in ejs and  then i am trying to access that array in a NodeJS POST method which is called on form submit.

this is how my array 'itm_mdf' looks like

[{"name":"COKE ZERO","id":"1048647"}].

I am passing the array as hidden field value as below

```
<form class="ui form" action="/items" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="modifiers" value=<%=JSON.stringify(itm_mdf)%>  
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">REORDER</button>
</form>
```

And i am accessing the array in Node JS post method like

```
app.post("/items",function(req,res){
console.log('itm_mdf *******'+req.body.modifiers);
}
```

But i see the array value is printed in Post method as below

itm_mdf *******[{"name":"COKE

and when i do a JSON.parse(req.body.modifiers) in the Post Method i get an error as SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

Could you please let me know what am i doing wrong here and what i need to do to fix this.

Comment: I don't know much about ejs, but it does look like your `<>` angle brackets are unbalanced at least.

Comment: Have you tried you to change `value=<%=JSON.stringify(itm_mdf)%` to `value='<%=JSON.stringify(itm_mdf)%'`  and hope that you don't have any single quotes in your data?

Answer (score 1):

The value is unquoted:

```
<input type="hidden" name="modifiers" value=<%=JSON.stringify(itm_mdf)%>
```

So it should be rendered like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="modifiers" value=[{"name":"COKE ZERO","id":"1048647"}]>
```

And that makes the `value='[{"name":"COKE '`

You need to quote it, but since JSON uses double quotes you must use singe quotes, and hope that you don't have single quotes in your data:

```
<input type="hidden" name="modifiers" value='<%=JSON.stringify(itm_mdf)%'>
```

The optimal solution is to make sure that you encode the value so that you don't have any quotes in the rendered data.

Comment: Thank you all . your solution worked. Much appreciated.